# Upload local folder structure (size upto 25GB) to SharePoint 2013 on premise document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, migration, document-migration

I want to migrate local folder which has upto 25GB of data (including documents and media files). Is there any free tool/script which I can use to upload data into SharePoint document library?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use One Drive for Business to sync all your local files to SharePoint, i hope it will take over night to sync all 25GB data(Based on the internet speed) and you can easily track the process by comparing the folder size or One Drive logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy them using Windows Explorer as you can open SharePoint Document Library in Windows Explorer from Ribbon. Copying all 25GB in one go might be problematic, so copy few folders at a time.

[image]

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-in-explorer-or-view-with-file-explorer-in-sharepoint-66b574bb-08b4-46b6-a6a0-435fd98194cc)

Comment: 25 GB is quite large. Make sure your site is having the correct quotas applied first.

Comment: @Jussi Palo there are a lot of nested folders and documents. I am afraid to use this option. Possibility of missing files.

Comment: Don't forget about URL length limits, reserved characters and blocked file-types!

Comment: @Christoffer those files and folders already removed.

Comment: Don't be afraid. As I said, copy files in smaller chunks, one or few folders at a time, and you can also do right-click + Properties of a copied folder to see file and folder number match.

Comment: You can map the site as network drive and then use xcopy/robocopy to move the files

Answer (score 0):

By default, the default document size threshold is set to 250MB, but can be changed to support the maximum boundary of 2GB. You can configure it from Central Admin :

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sammykailini/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

25GB data is so large, it is better that you upload the document in batch.

Comment: How? Any script/ free tool you can suggest?